# Android app firestore issue when minify is true

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am using the firestore database to store some todos and it works fine when I tried in debug + minify off. So, I create a release app and the production app was crashing continuously. The only difference between releases and debug apps are minified features and debug libs. I flipped minify to true in debug mode and got this error. Plz, help...

```
        2022-06-23 22:36:26.123 20375-20375/sample.android.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: sample.android.app, PID: 20375
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Internal error in Cloud Firestore (24.1.1).
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue.lambda$panic$3(AsyncQueue.java:539)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue.$r8$lambda$jx84dqgUsF4ojecSMurRqFLFD1Y(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6762)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: com.google.android.gms.tasks.RuntimeExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.AssertionError: impossible
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzw.getResult(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.1:3)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.FirestoreChannel.lambda$runBidiStreamingRpc$0(FirestoreChannel.java:117)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.FirestoreChannel.$r8$lambda$ThFui-hvcsrVGYxlBtcTH5vVbvE(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.FirestoreChannel$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onComplete(Unknown Source:6)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzi.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.1:1)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:458)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor$DelayedStartFactory.run(AsyncQueue.java:234)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.AssertionError: impossible
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzz.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.1:2)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.ThrottledForwardingExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ThrottledForwardingExecutor.java:54)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.ThrottledForwardingExecutor.$r8$lambda$MfIJbVuxZtLwosAgPzPA-cU66Ko(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.ThrottledForwardingExecutor$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:4)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
     Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: impossible
        at java.lang.Enum$1.create(Enum.java:272)
        at java.lang.Enum$1.create(Enum.java:262)
        at libcore.util.BasicLruCache.get(BasicLruCache.java:58)
        at java.lang.Enum.getSharedConstants(Enum.java:289)
        at java.lang.Class.getEnumConstantsShared(Class.java:2423)
        at java.util.EnumSet.getUniverse(EnumSet.java:407)
        at java.util.EnumSet.noneOf(EnumSet.java:109)
        at java.util.EnumSet.of(EnumSet.java:235)
        at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpChannelBuilder.<clinit>(OkHttpChannelBuilder.java:575)
        at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpChannelBuilder.forTarget(OkHttpChannelBuilder.java:156)
        at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpChannelProvider.builderForTarget(OkHttpChannelProvider.java:47)
        at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpChannelProvider.builderForTarget(OkHttpChannelProvider.java:27)
        at io.grpc.ManagedChannelBuilder.forTarget(ManagedChannelBuilder.java:76)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.GrpcCallProvider.initChannel(GrpcCallProvider.java:99)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.GrpcCallProvider.lambda$initChannelTask$6(GrpcCallProvider.java:242)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.GrpcCallProvider.$r8$lambda$SCD5iiibQ8l4haiO8ofSfE0wIJg(Unknown Source:0)
2022-06-23 22:36:26.124 20375-20375/sample.android.app E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.firebase.firestore.remote.GrpcCallProvider$$ExternalSyntheticLambda6.call(Unknown Source:2)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzz.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.1:1)
            ... 6 more
     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: values []
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2068)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2047)
        at java.lang.Enum$1.create(Enum.java:268)
            ... 23 more
```

Comment: check Firestore documentation pages if the have provided any Proguard rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched for almost 2-3 hours but didn't find any solution because the problem was created by myself. So, debugging gave me a simple solution. If any android developer facing this kind of issue while using firebase in minifying enabled mode.

**Check your proguard rules for firestore and data models.**

that's it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).